# Who pays for treatment and living expenses of former Pakistan's President Pervez Musharraf?

Tags: international-relations, pakistan, united-arab-emirates

Politics aside, I see news that [former Pakistan's President Pervez Musharraf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pervez_Musharraf) is in Dubai for few years, I am wondering who pays for his hospital and his family stay?

Comment: Do you have any indication that he is not simply paying for it out of his own pockets? Are his costs there so big that this would not be realistic from his official income during his time as president?

Answer (score -1):

Officially, they earn a pension for their life, like any government employees. For Non-ministers, the pension and other benefits expire after 4/5 years, depending on the election cycle. (If cycle is 5 years, Ex-MP will get pension for the next 5 years, if he loses. If he wins, he makes the salary)

Many countries constitutions are a first-class copy of British/US governments. So, the laws would be relatable in your nation.

He was a dictator, so he must have made some money, unofficially*. So, those funds could be used too. Also, they get medical aid for their life. (Only Ministers), so the government pays for medical, if the required treatment isn't available in the nation, as per standards*.

Comment: Please try to add references to support your answer.

Comment: @kris-2025, I guess in sentence "the laws would be relatable in **your** nation." you mean **that** nation. 

To ask question, I guess one need not be only asking for home country..